# Prevent vscode Python unittests from opening final sys.exit() on test failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

Running python3.8 unittests with `pytest` under `vscode` - pytest exists with a `sys.exit(1)` when tests fail.  This itself is OK - but VSCode insists on opening the line of `pytest.py` when this happens, which is quite inconvenient because:

1. the debugger pops open `pytest.py` on the `sys.exit(...)` call, shifting UI focus away from whatever file I was working in, requiring me to navigate back.
2. in the file browser the tree expands to display `pytest.py` - which means the entire `venv` package tree expands, forcing me to do a bunch of scrolling to re-hide it.

How can I make vscode not open `pytest.py`?  The test failure output in the cmd window is necessary and sufficient.  I'd be OK if the solution prevents *any* `sys.exit()` from causing an implicit breakpoint.

---

one detail that might be important here is we're running these as `"type":"python","request":"launch"` in `launch.json` *not* `"type":"python","request":"unittest"` - the reason is this allows for the unittests to be run identically to how the `CI` runners work.  However, this launch.json entry *does* have `"justMyCode":true`, and `pytest.py` is external code - so it still should not be breaking on anything (?) in that external code.

Comment: Could you please use a specific example to minimize the problem you encounter so that people can better help you.

Comment: @JillCheng - certainly agree with your statement - but not sure how to make the above any simpler.  When the test fails, VSCode insists on breaking on, and opening the `pytest.py` file

Comment: I tested the unittest in VS Code and it didn't open other python files when the test failed. Since Python's test function is provided by the Python extension, it is recommended that you try to reinstall it. In addition, you could also refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) to check the use of the test.

Comment: @JillCheng - ah, MS :) well, thanks for replying; in github I've seen much less responsive answers from Microsoft employees...   I'm running my tests as a `"type":"python"` in launch.json, not `"unittest"`, because this allows running them the same way `CI` does.  I _do_ have `"justMyCode":true` (obviously `pytest.py` is external code).  Is this relevant to the reproduction?  Did you try a `python` launch, with `justMyCode==False` of a file that `sys.exit(1)`?

Comment: @JillCheng - I uninstalled/reinstalled as requested, and I've tried again to setup the ms-python unittest (pytest) support.  I have all variables mentioned in the url you provided set, and I have set both `"pythonPath":` (in settings.json) and `"env"{"PYTHONPATH":` (in both the `"request":"unittest"` in launch.json and in my settings.json) **identically** to how is working successfully running `pytest` ~manually with my `"request":"launch"` unit test "config". .  the built-in unittest discover fails, though, not finding my local packages - which indicates it's not respecting `PYTHONPATH` env?

Comment: -Thank you for your willingness to try VS Code unittesting, How to understand "not finding my local packages"? In my "launch.json", it is the normal default configuration (because it configures and debugs the python code), and the test settings are in "settings.json". (For example: `"python.testing.unittestArgs" : [
         "-v",
         "-s",
         "./b",
         "-p",
         "test_*.py"
     ],
     "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
     "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
     "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,`)